# Jest snapshot tests failing in GitHub Actions due to missing color

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, github-actions, snapshot

I am having an issue while trying to set up a Github action that runs my Jest test suite. It [fails](https://github.com/M-Scott-Lassiter/jest-geojson/runs/6515392881?check_suite_focus=true) due to using snapshots. It appears the issue might be caused by the colored formatting on the error messages.

Screenshot provided because I couldn't get the color formatting to copy over to this question using only markdown.

The tests all pass locally, so I know the logic works. It is an issue in the Github test runner, but I'm not sure how to address it. If I remove those particular tests, it will drop my code coverage. How do I get the tests to pass in this environment?

[image: CI/CD environment showing where test fails]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you run your tests with `npm test`, you can set the environment variable `FORCE_COLOR` and thereby make jest use color in GitHub Actions as well:

```yaml
- run: npm test
  env:
    FORCE_COLOR: true
```